# Reusing design elements PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

When building a GUI application using python and the qt framework. I would like to reuse certain UI elements without defining them over and over again. In my example I would like to create a drop down menu defining the number of rows with y(number) and result(number)

Application example

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton,
                             QLineEdit,  QGridLayout, QLabel)
from math import sqrt

class program(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Program')

        flow = QLabel('x1')
        pressuredrop_1 = QLabel('y1')
        pressuredrop_2 = QLabel('y2 ')
        kv = QLabel('result 1')
        kv_2 = QLabel('result 2')

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)

        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.setGeometry(300,300,300,150)

        self.btn = QPushButton('Calculate', self)

        self.flow = QLineEdit(self)
        self.pd = QLineEdit(self)
        self.result = QLineEdit(self)

        self.pd_2 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.kvresult_2 = QLineEdit(self)

        grid.addWidget(flow, 1,0)
        grid.addWidget(self.flow, 1, 1)

        grid.addWidget(pressuredrop_1, 2,0)
        grid.addWidget(self.pd, 2, 1)
        grid.addWidget(pressuredrop_2, 3,0)
        grid.addWidget(self.pd_2, 3, 1)

        grid.addWidget(kv, 2,2)
        grid.addWidget(self.result, 2,3)
        grid.addWidget(kv_2, 3,2)
        grid.addWidget(self.kvresult_2, 3,3)

        grid.addWidget(self.btn, 4,1)

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.calculate)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.calculate_2)

        self.show()
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I guess you can create a class with all the GUI initialization and then instantiate it how many times you want. This way you will "reuse" the GUI structure you created

Comment: So you want to dynamically change the number of rows of `yn`/`result n` widgets, depending on user input?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. @ekhumoro yes that is exactly what I mean.

Comment: @Eduardo That means I have to define them all on forehand? For every row I need to add at least 8 lines of code. Can't this be done smaller/easier?